# R Scraping IMDB: Better way to handle missing information?

Tags: r, web-scraping, missing-data, rvest, imdb

I am following this site to get information from IMDB: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/

However, some of the data is missing from IMDB.  The website suggests doing a visual inspection and writing a function like this:

```
for (i in c(39,73,80,89)){

a<-metascore_data[1:(i-1)]

b<-metascore_data[i:length(metascore_data)]

metascore_data<-append(a,list("NA"))

metascore_data<-append(metascore_data,b)

}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this issue programmatically?

Comment: What information are you trying to scrape? Also add the link from where you want to scrape.

Comment: Here's the link I am using: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&online_availability=US/IMDbTV&start=1251&ref_=adv_nxt.  webpage <- my_read_html(URL). genre_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.genre') genre_data <- html_text(genre_data_html). This returns 48 items when there are 50 movies on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me :

```
library(rvest)
URL <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&online_availability=US/IMDbTV&start=1251&ref_=adv_nxt'
webpage <- read_html(URL)
genres <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes('span.genre') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  trimws()
```

This returns 50 values :

```
genres
# [1] "Comedy, Romance"              "Action, Crime, Drama"        
# [3] "Action, Horror, Sci-Fi"       "Action, Adventure, Thriller" 
# [5] "Adventure, Comedy, Family"    "Comedy"                      
# [7] "Action, Adventure, Thriller"  "Comedy, Drama, Romance"      
# [9] "Comedy"                       "Comedy"                      
#[11] "Action, Adventure, Drama"     "Action, Thriller"            
#[13] "Action, Crime, Thriller"      "Mystery, Thriller"           
#[15] "Crime, Drama, Thriller"       "Drama, Horror"               
#[17] "Animation, Drama, War"        "Drama, Thriller"             
#[19] "Action, Crime, Drama"         "Drama, Sci-Fi"               
#[21] "Adventure, Comedy, Family"    "Crime, Drama"                
#[23] "Action, Adventure, Thriller"  "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi"   
#[25] "Thriller"                     "Comedy, Crime"               
#[27] "Comedy, Romance"              "Action, Biography, Drama"    
#[29] "Adventure, Comedy"            "Crime, Drama, Thriller"      
#[31] "Drama, Sci-Fi, Thriller"      "Comedy, Romance"             
#[33] "Action, Drama, Thriller"      "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi"   
#[35] "Action, Crime, Drama"         "Action, Adventure, Drama"    
#[37] "Action, Thriller"             "Action, Drama, War"          
#[39] "Drama, Sci-Fi, Thriller"      "Animation, Adventure, Family"
#[41] "Drama, Romance"               "Action, Drama, Fantasy"      
#[43] "Action, Adventure, Fantasy"   "Comedy, Crime, Drama"        
#[45] "Action, Crime, Drama"         "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi"   
#[47] "Drama, Romance"               "Animation, Family, Fantasy"  
#[49] "Action, Adventure, Fantasy"   "Mystery, Thriller"
```

Comment: @Ronak_Shah I copied your code and ran it, but still only got 48.

Comment: @Ronak_Shah 'code'URL <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&online_availability=US/IMDbTV&start=1251&ref_=adv_nxt'
> webpage <- read_html(URL)
> genres <- webpage %>%
+     html_nodes('span.genre') %>%
+     html_text() %>%
+     trimws() 'code'

Comment: @Ronak_Shah `code`[1] "Comedy" "Comedy, Drama, History""Action"                      
 [4] "Action, Adventure, Drama" "Family" "Family"                      
 [7] "Drama" "Comedy, Family, Romance" "Family"                      
[10] "Action" "Thriller" "Comedy, Drama"               
[13] "Action" "Drama" "Animation"                   
[16] "Animation, Adventure, Family" "Animation" "Action, Romance, Sport"      
[19] "Drama, Fantasy, Mystery" "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi" "Drama, Thriller, Crime"      
[22] "Comedy" "Comedy, Family"  "Drama, Family"               
`code`

Comment: @Ronak_Shah `code`[25] "Family, Fantasy, Musical" "Thriller" "Drama"                       
[28] "Action, Crime, Drama" "Drama, Romance, Thriller" "Western"                     
[31] "Drama, Family" "Drama" "Comedy, Family"              
[34] "Drama, History" "Drama" "Crime, Drama"                
[37] "Comedy, Drama, Romance" "Comedy" "Crime, Horror, Thriller"     
[40] "Drama, Mystery, Thriller" "Drama, Horror, Thriller" "Animation, Comedy"           
[43] "Action" "Comedy, Horror" "Comedy, Horror"              
[46] "Comedy" "Action" "Drama"  `code`

Comment: Does `length(genres)` return 48? That's strange because as shown it works for me. Do you have firewall or anti-virus which is stopping the scraping?

Comment: Length(genres) returns 48. @Ronak_Shah

Comment: rvest version is ‘0.3.5’ @Ronak_Shah

Comment: I have the same package Version and strangely enough this works for me as shown. Not sure why is it different for you.

Comment: I tried your code on a totally different network, but got 48.  My first run was with no antivirus and no firewall.  The second was with an antivirus and with firewall, but I don't think it would affect the result.  So, like you not sure why the difference. @Ronak_Shah

Comment: I was just looking at the website brought up by the URL.  The first movie is "Kung Fu of Seven Steps".  It is Action, Drama.  However, the first genre in your returned information is "Comedy, Romance".  Could you check on that? @Ronak_Shah